# Access variable from function inside of nested function

Tags: php, function, scope

In PHP, you have to use the `global` keyword in order to access a variable from the global scope when inside of a function. However, how can you access a 
variable within the scope of a parent function?

#### In the example:

```
function foo() {
    $content = 'foobar';

    function bar() {
        echo $content; // echos nothing
    }
}
```

**How can I access the `$content` variable?**

Comment: See the linked question's accepted answer. Gives you a smart way to do what you want using closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. **Give `$content` as a parameter**

   ```php
   function foo() {
       $content = 'foobar';

       function bar($content) {
           echo $content . '1'; // 'foobar1'
       }

       bar();
   }

   foo();
   ```
2. **Use closures** ([PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)) (PHP 5.3.0+)

   Please note that the function declaration is a bit different compared to the 'conventional way' of declaring functions.

   ```php
   function foo() {
       $content = 'foobar';

       $bar = function() use ($content) {
           echo $content . '1';
       };  // <-- As it's an assignment, end with a ';'

       $bar();
   }

   foo();  // 'foobar1'
   ```

Comment: I was really hoping that there would be a more elegant solution, but I'm guessing that this will have to do.

Comment: Using variables within functions is generally done with parameters. So I'd recommend the first one but that depends on the functions and other parameters etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer was very informative for me.  The closure approach was perfect for what I was trying to do.